# zsh: command not found: compass

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass

I've been trying to install compass/sass, and it does install/bundle except it...doesn't install. I can't use any commands. When I enter 'compass compile' I get the error

```
zsh: command not found: compass
```

When I try to run my project I get this error on rails server:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
```

I tried uninstalling the gems and using sudo to install, didn't work.
I tried running gem update --system, doesn't work

when I run which -a gem, I get:

```
/Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/shims/gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

If anybody has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. thank you so much!

Comment: Did you [rbenv rehash](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-rehash)?

Comment: Yup, I got: rbenv: cannot rehash: /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim exist  unfortunately.